# How to get existing token with Github API

Tags: github, github-api

The token attribute is deprecated in many OAuth Authorizations API responses according [official doc](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#create-a-new-authorization)

So how can I get existing token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not possible anymore. The token will be returned only when you create it via the API, but it won't be returned if you try to fetch it afterwards.

Can you clarify why you need to fetch existing tokens?

Comment: I am developing an APP for github.I save the token in local AccountManager,If the user logout the accoutManager will lose the token,So next time the user login,the app will fail to recreate the same token so it  has to get existing token from remote server.

Comment: Have you considered creating the token with a specific description, so that you can find if by that afterwards, then delete it, and then re-create it?

Comment: Aha,give me five！My solution is the same as yours！

Comment: Very common use case is to set use of it up on another machine.